# How to update data directly in row?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem with my code. I have a php script where i, in a while, i write a table in html with html name and html value attr with the data of database, like the printscreen above
My table was assembled with input inside the TDs, to be able to "edit" directly in the table, without MODAL or redirection

```
</thead>
    <tbody id="corpoTabela">
        <?php
        $i = 1;
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) :;
        ?>

            <tr>
                <form name="presencaForm" id="presencaForm" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" id="idcrmmedico" name="idcrmmedico" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></input>
```

See that the opening of the form tag is inside the while, that is, for each row of the table, for each TR, I have a form (all with the same name)

The end of the form tag still inside php while. The Button, who receives the ID referring to the record in the DB, has the same name of the form

```
<td><button id="d" name="presencaForm" value="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Atualizar</a></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit" id="" name="deletamedico" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Excluir</button>
                    </td>
                </form>
            </tr>

    <?php
        endwhile;
    }
    ?>
    </tbody>
```

This is my ajax script, which updates the data in the database without refreshing the page and returning me a success message.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#presencaForm').on('submit', function(event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 $("#alert").css('display', 'none');
                 console.log("Botão Clicado!");
                 $.ajax({
                     url: "DAO/medico/update.php",
                     method: "POST",
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     dataType: "json",
                     success: function(data) {
                         if (data[0] == true) {
                             $("#success").html('Médico ' + data[1] + ' atualizado com sucesso');
                             $("#success").show();
                             setTimeout(function() {
                                 $("#success").hide();
                             }, 5000);
                         }
                     }
                 })
             });
        });
        
    </script>
```

The problem is that if i try to refresh the second line, the page just refreshes.

I used the code below to check, and I saw that all buttons return only the first record in the LOG.
Is there any way to update the data as I want, right in the table?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("button[name='presencaForm']").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                for (var i = 1; i < document.getElementById("dataTable").rows.length; i++) {
                    console.log($('#idcrmmedico').val());
                }
                var val = document.getElementById('d').value;
                var x = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows.length;
                
            });
```

Comment: Providing code instead of images of code helps to get so much faster recommendations from the community

Answer (score 0):

`id` is unique,if you want to control a group of `form`,you can use `class`.

For example:

```
<form class="presencaForm" method="POST">
```

Then in your javascript:

```
$('.presencaForm').on('submit', function(event) {
```

Comment: The problem now is the button of seccond row update the data of the first row. In fact, only the first row is being updated

Comment: The problem now is every button update the last data/row, in truth

Comment: Because in your code the form id of second row is same as the first row, id is unique, so your code can only update the first row. You should try my code to fix it.@FelipeMachado